# highlighted Item of looping selector WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I want to know that how can I get the highlight item's index for loopingselector toolkit on window phone 7. I am using the looping selector by binding with datasource.
Anyone who can help ?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

This control exposes a `SelectedItem` property. Bind that to an item of the same data type you have in your bound collection.